# How to set timeout in Mocha root-level hooks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mocha.js

I want to set a timeout for the root-level hook for Mocha testing.

My root-level hook looks like this, in `test/setup.ts`:

```js
import * as database from '../src/database/_db'

export const mochaHooks = {
    /* Connect to the DB before running any tests */
    beforeAll(done: () => void) {
        database.initialize(done)
    },
    
    /* Close the DB connect after all tests finished */
    afterAll(done: () => void) {
        database.close(done);
    }
};
```

and this is loaded via `--require test/setup.ts`. The DB connection takes a long time so I'd like to increase the timeout value.

Running Mocha with `-t 10000` works but that also sets timeouts for every test.

I've also tried to add `this.timeout(3000)` in `BeforeAll` but got `✖ ERROR: test/setup.ts:10:14 - error TS2339: Property 'timeout' does not exist on type '{ beforeAll(done: () => void): void; afterAll(done: () => void): void; }'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the doc [ARROW FUNCTIONS](https://mochajs.org/#arrow-functions):

> Passing arrow functions (aka “lambdas”) to Mocha is discouraged. Lambdas lexically bind `this` and cannot access the Mocha context.

Test context isn't being bound when using arrow functions. So you can't use `this.timeout()`.

You should change the arrow function to [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Function_declarations) which consists of the `function` keyword.